# PDO Insert not working

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo

I'm trying to take a record from one table in my database and place it in another table (as a backup of the data - needs to be kept for 7 years, including deleted data). The select works, the delete works, but the insert doesn't.
What's wrong? What can I do to fix it?

Code:

```
////////// DELETE STUDENT RECORD /////////
///// step 1 - copy all data to exStudentInfo with removal date //////

$studentID = $_REQUEST['sID'];
// pull student data from the database //
$query = "SELECT * FROM studentinfo WHERE studentID=" . $studentID;
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement ->execute();
while($row = $statement->fetchObject())
    {
        $studentFirst = $row->studentFirst;
        $studentLast = $row->studentLast;
        $studentDOB = $row->studentDOB;
        $studentGrade = $row->studentGrade;
        $studentClass = $row->studentClass;
        $studentAllergy = $row->studentAllergy;
        $studentFam = $row->studentFam;
        $removeDate = date("Y-m-d");
    }
```

SOLVED: The problem is in $query... I've used ordinary apostrophes (') rather than the correct backtick (`) - and I'd forgotten to include the photo field in the bound values.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO 'sundayschool'.'exstudentinfo' ('studentID' ,'studentFirst' ,'studentLast' ,'famID' ,'studentDOB' ,'studentGrade' ,'studentClass' ,'studentAllergy' ,'studentPhoto' ,'removeDate') VALUES (:id, :first, :last, :fam, :dob, :grade, :class, :allergy, :date)";
```

Correct form:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `sundayschool`.`exstudentinfo` (`studentID` ,`studentFirst` ,`studentLast` ,`famID` ,`studentDOB` ,`studentGrade` ,`studentClass` ,`studentAllergy` ,`studentPhoto` ,`removeDate`) VALUES (:id, :first, :last, :fam, :dob, :grade, :class, :allergy,:photo,:date)";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':id',$studentID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(':first',$studentFirst, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':last',$studentLast, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':fam',$studentFam, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(':dob',$studentDOB, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':grade',$studentGrade, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':class',$studentClass, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':allergy',$studentAllergy, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':date',$removeDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();

///// step 2 - Delete student from studentinfo table //////
$stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM studentinfo WHERE studentID=:id");
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $studentID);
$stmt->execute();
echo $studentFirst . " " . $studentLast . " has been removed from the system (and backed up)";
echo "<p><a href='admin.php'>&lt;&lt; Return to administration page</a></p>";
```

Comment: Quotes don't work. Where did you see that you have to use quotes and that it has to be a single quote? Look at your insert statement once more.

Comment: please refer to the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) on the **right connect options**. Then tell us which errors you've got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, your line:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO 'sundayschool'.'exstudentinfo' ('studentID' ,'studentFirst' ,'studentLast' ,'famID' ,'studentDOB' ,'studentGrade' ,'studentClass' ,'studentAllergy' ,'studentPhoto' ,'removeDate') VALUES (:id, :first, :last, :fam, :dob, :grade, :class, :allergy, :date)";
```

Needs to change to use backticks instead of single quotes:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `sundayschool`.`exstudentinfo` 
(
  `studentID`,
  `studentFirst`,
  `studentLast`,
  `famID`,
  `studentDOB`,
  `studentGrade`,
  `studentClass`,
  `studentAllergy`,
  `studentPhoto`,
  `removeDate`
) 

VALUES (
  :id, 
  :first, 
  :last, 
  :fam, 
  :dob, 
  :grade, 
  :class, 
  :allergy, 
  :photo, 
  :date
)";
```

Answer (score 5):

It keeps me in constant wonder why everyone so eager to write **several screens of code** for the every simple insert.
What's the point in fetching object if you can get an array which is ready to be inserted into execute?

```
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
$row['removeDate'] = date("Y-m-d");
$query = "INSERT INTO exstudentinfo (studentID ,studentFirst,studentLast,famID,studentDOB,studentGrade,studentClass,studentAllergy,studentPhoto,removeDate) VALUES (:id, :first, :last, :fam, :dob, :grade, :class, :allergy, :date)";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($row);
```

without double assigning and binding!

not to mention that mysql can let you to do that [in a single query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)

```
INSERT INTO exstudentinfo SELECT *, CURDATE() as removeDate FROM studentinfo
```

Comment: I'll look into that (especially the INSERT .. SELECT). I wonder, though, if that is a MySQL particular query, and if so, if that defeats one of the purposes of PDO?

Answer (score 2):

You should really add proper error handling, but the problem is that you want to insert 9 values into 10 fields and you are using quotes for your field and table names:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO sundayschool.exstudentinfo
           (studentID ,studentFirst ,studentLast ,famID ,studentDOB ,studentGrade ,studentClass ,studentAllergy ,studentPhoto ,removeDate)
           // 10 fields
         VALUES
           (:id, :first, :last, :fam, :dob, :grade, :class, :allergy, :date)";
           // 9 values, photo is missing
```

If you need to quote for example mysql reserved words, you need to use the backtick for your table or field names:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `sundayschool`.`exstudentinfo`
            // etc.
```

Comment: Thanks, missed the photo one, but that wasn't the issue. Issue was that I needed the back quotes. At least that's what seemed to work.

Comment: @Schwarz.Oz Not really, you don't seem to use any reserved words or numerical names.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it without the apostrophes, but it didn't insert (plus had fixed up the fields thing). Went back through and put backticks in - and it worked. Not sure why. About to try error trapping it.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the part where you insert `studentPhoto` between `allergy` and `date`. You're trying to insert 10 fields but you're only providing information for 9.

Also, lose the quotes here. You don't need them:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `sundayschool`.`exstudentinfo` (studentID ,studentFirst ,studentLast ,famID ,studentDOB ,studentGrade ,studentClass ,studentAllergy ,studentPhoto ,removeDate) VALUES (:id, :first, :last, :fam, :dob, :grade, :class, :allergy, :date)";
```

Remember to add `studentPhoto`